# Wrong changing values in Slider Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, slider, android-jetpack-compose

When I change values in Slider(from User) I have experience issue. Slider Point goes faster or slower comparing to my touches(it goes faster to 0 value, checked in -100..0 values too). Compose Version: `1.0.0-beta8`. My code:

```kotlin
var sliderState by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
Slider(
   value = sliderState,
   steps = 0,
   valueRange = 0f..100f,
   onValueChange = { newValue ->
     sliderState = newValue
   },
   colors = sliderColors
)
```

Video example: [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ztroNB9Upd37hoQwwrsxWu-Jb7bg-sF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have just tried your code and it has worked perfectly with me.

Comment: Maybe it's because of your emulator.

Comment: On my real device I had the same result

Comment: Well apparently you are just modifying the `sliderState` somewhere in an incorrect way.

Comment: I had a similar issue. It originated in me using discrete values (`.toInt()`), not floats.